# regex replace with empty line

Tags: regex

hi im using notepad++ and regex

i have empty lines in my text and i want to replace empty lines with this characters</>

my text like this

Substitutes (the-)

elect (the-)

righteous (the)

i want to be like this

Substitutes (the-)

</>

elect (the-)

</>

righteous (the)

</>

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^$
Replace: </>
```